# Deep reference ..? | Intertools.product()

Tags: python, product, pass-by-reference, python-itertools

The following (pseudo) code should insert **only one** ZERO per pair

```py
from itertools import product

In [321]: 
for p in  product([[1],[2]],[[4],[5]]):
     p[0].insert(0,0)
     print(p)
Out [321]  
([0, 1], [4])
([0, 0, 1], [5])
([0, 2], [4])
([0, 0, 2], [5])
    
In [322]: 
for p in  product([[1],[2]],[[4],[5]]):
    q = p[:]    
    q[0].insert(0,0)
    print(q)
Out [322]  
([0, 1], [4])
([0, 0, 1], [5])
([0, 2], [4])
([0, 0, 2], [5])
```

I know that the reason is that the `product()` method passes the item by reference, but ..... I cant change its behavior..

Any solution?

---

[`itertools.product(*iterables, repeat=1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)

Comment: Just a terminology note: although it is frequently mislabled as pass by reference, this behavior is not caused by pass by reference, because Python doesn't support that evaluation strategy.

Comment: In any case, you just need to use a deep copy instead of the shallow `q = p[:]`

Comment: In other words, `p[:]` makes s copy of the outer tupple, but does not copy the inner lists (`q[0] is p[0]`!).

Comment: Use `q = copy.deepcopy(p)`

Comment: Rather than using `insert` at all, put the zero in the list *before* computing the product: `product([[0,1], [0,2]], [[4],[5]])`.